# Blur image using Python-errors

Tags: python, image-processing, convolution

I need to blur an image by taking a kernel `K` and averaging the values in the 2D array and setting the center value to the average of `K`.  Here is the code I have written to do so...

```
def Clamp(pix):
    pix = abs(pix)
    if pix > 255:
        pix = 255
    return pix

def Convolve2D(image1, K, image2):
    img = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0, 0), image1)
    img.save(image2)
    secondimage=graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0,0),image2)
    h = img.getHeight()
    w = img.getWidth()
    A = [[0]*h for y in range(w)]
    B = [[0]*w for x in range(h)]
    #iterate over all rows (ignore 1-pixel borders) 
    for v in range(1, h-3):
        graphics.update() # this updates the output for each row
        # for every row, iterate over all columns (again ignore 1-pixel borders)
        for u in range(1, w-3):
            #A[u][v] = 0
            #B[u][v] = 0
            # for every pixel, iterate over region of overlap between
            #   input image and 3x3 kernel centered at current pixel
            for i in range (0, 3):
                for j in range (0, 3):
                    A[u][v] = A[u][v] + B[v+i][u+j] * K[i][j]
            r, g, b = img.getPixel(u, v)
            if (r * A[u][v] >= 255):
                Clamp(r)
            else:
                r = r * A[u][v]
            if (g * A[u][v] >= 255):
                Clamp(g)
            else:
                g = g * A[u][v]
            if (b * A[u][v] >= 255):
                Clamp(b)
            else:
                b = b * A[u][v]
            newcolor = graphics.color_rgb(r, g, b)
            secondimage.setPixel(u, v , newcolor)
    print("Not yet implemented") # to be removed
    secondimage.save(image2)
    secondimage.move(secondimage.getWidth()/2, secondimage.getHeight()/2)
    win = graphics.GraphWin(secondimage, secondimage.getWidth(), secondimage.getHeight())
    secondimage.draw(win)


def Blur3(image1, image2):
    K = [[1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9], [1/9, 1/9, 1/9]]
    return Convolve2D(image1, K, image2)
```

This is the image I am trying to blur

[image]

This is what comes out of my code

[image]

is it possibly my if and else statements and the clamp function that is doing this? I just want a blurred image to come out like this

[image]

Comment: I guess you didnt handle borders ! take a look at http://www.songho.ca/dsp/convolution/convolution.html

Comment: how should I do that? I thought I handled them with `for v in range(1, h-1)` and `for u in range(1, w-1):` ?

Comment: why -1? your kernel size is 3! so you should it with -3

Comment: this one also https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:s18nEBHxp0YJ:www.cs.ucf.edu/~mtappen/cap5415/lecs/lec1.pdf+border+handling+image+blurring+filetype+:pdf&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgZcxYDaukikMNdDgSNqSvcNCa22SjG4quE9UG_YaRAAe_P_N3Ly8HLrBW8JK3l69wgihT_qt-EBi0bHFKZgoZvH7hFYX47yzTHwkh8Vn7glHq-om1rbnCAIZDtZhxWKoOBUczd&sig=AHIEtbRZIrMsnciIrEZGoZ8oxivSCgtqyQ

Comment: I did it with -3 but now all I get is a big black screen with what looks like a 3 pixel border around it displaying the border of my original image

Comment: can you please add one sample image? what is the of your image?what happened after doing Mark suggestion?

Comment: could my if and else statements be making it do that? would that mean that all the values are going above 255 or below 0 due to the clamp function?

Comment: but your getting this error in the first iteration? can you update the code if you made any changes ?what is ´clamp´function ?

Comment: I updated the code and added pictures, the clamp function is saying that if the value of the pixel goes above 255 then make it 255

Comment: I was going to mention that the out of bounds indexes were only the first of many bugs, but I see you've discovered it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You've initialized `A` and `B` to empty lists with a size of `0`. You need to initialize them instead to be the size of the image, in both dimensions.

```
A = [[0]*w for y in range(h)]
```

**Edit:** Your second problem is that you're defining the kernel with `1/9` which is an integer division yielding `0`.

Comment: what do I wan't `B` to be?

Comment: do I wan't it to be `B = [[0]*h for x in range(w)]` ?

Comment: I tried to do `1//9` and I am still getting the issue where I get a big black screen and a tiny border of the picture like I show in my second picture, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do this :

```
for v in range(h):
        graphics.update() # this updates the output for each row
        for u in range(w):
             for i in range (0, 3):
                for j in range (0, 3):
                    if v-i>=0 and u-j>=0 and v+i<=256 and u+j<=256  :
                        img[u][v] = img[u][v] + img[v-i][u-j] * K[i][j]
```

this should work!

Can you please tell me why you have two images A, B and blur image A using B? I mean :

```
                    A[u][v] = A[u][v] + B[v+i][u+j] * K[i][j]
```

Here I add a code which works for gray scale image,you can expand it for your need!

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

Img=mpimg.imread('GrayScaleImg.jpg')
kernel=towDimGuassKernel(size)

def conv2D(I,kernel):

    filterWidth=kernel.shape[0]
    half=filterWidth/2


    bluredImg=np.zeros(I.shape)
    for imgRow in range(I.shape[0]):
        print imgRow
        for imgCol in range(I.shape[1]):
            for filterRow in range(filterWidth):
                for filterCol in range(filterWidth):
                    if imgRow-filterRow>=0 and imgCol-filterCol>=0 and imgRow+filterRow<=256 and imgCol+filterCol<=256  :
                        bluredImg[imgRow,imgCol]+=I[imgRow-filterRow,imgCol-filterCol]*kernel[filterRow,filterCol]



    return bluredImg
```

Comment: i tried that and i get that at `A[u][v] = A[u][v] + A[v-i][u-j] * K[i][j]`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: I think I need to change `A = [[0]*h for y in range(w)]`

Comment: I changed A back to B in the algorithm and I got out an image but it wasn't blurred...

Comment: sorry I made a mistake , you dont need to define A, B just your img if it is numpy array!

Comment: now it tells me this `img[u][v] = img[u][v] + img[v-i][u-j] * K[i][j]
TypeError: 'Image' object does not support indexing`

Comment: what is the type of img? why  dont use scipy or matplotlib module for image processing purposes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the image type is a .gif, is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: I mean what the result of type(img), isn't it an array?

Comment: you can check it by ´print type(img)´, I  edited my post! check it out